# Twisted Server Sent Events accessing using Internet Explorer

Tags: python, internet-explorer, real-time, twisted, server-sent-events

I am working on a project that requires real time update. So, long ago, I decided to go with using Twisted SSE Handler (cyclone.sse). The project is at an end. And all the pub/sub stuff is good on all the browsers except Internet Explorer. IE doesn't support SSE. How do I get pub-sub working on IE without change of code in server-side? Also long polling will not help as I am using cyclone.sse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question is a little weird. But I just found the answer. I had to go with *long polling*. looks like, I have to write a framework which falls-back to long polling when server sent events are not supported. Answering just in case anyone comes for reference in future.

Comment: Is there still no support for SSE in any IE version?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Nope. there is no support yet as of this day.